# xubuntu 21.10 g++ gtk4 "error: ‘gtk_container_add’ was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gtk4

xubuntu 21.10 g++ gtk4 give me next error while I compile my source codes in console (terminal)
"error: ‘gtk_container_add’ was not declared in this scope".

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Which libs (deb packets) I need install to my xubuntu 21.10 and which files (libs) I need include to my c++ source codes?

Answer (score 0):

That particular function was removed in GTK4.

See the GTK3->GTK4 migration guide: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#reduce-the-use-of-generic-container-apis